# Has anyone else experienced an incorrect sha256 check sum for the recent android-studio on linux?

Tags: android, android-studio

The linux version(android-studio-ide-183.5692245-linux.tar.gz ) of android-studio fails sha256 checksum. The bytes(1087839319) match up but the hash values don't.
this is the hash o/p of my download: 45a89a650b4283bb536359bda32c6659850d044ea0dbc2d6bb066d35caf39dcb
[hash and bytes image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR3PL.png)
this is what's on the website:
https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads
35eb8c74837d1aab59229101fc91568a607ac04854a40209f7a0ba7ac0601924
The archives also list 1087839319 bytes
https://developer.android.com/studio/archive
can someone verify if the hash on the site is correct? Thanks.

Comment: I just downloaded `android-studio-ide-183.5692245-linux.tar.gz` and my SHA256 hash matches what's on the site (`35eb8c74837d1aab59229101fc91568a607ac04854a40209f7a0ba7ac0601924`)

Comment: Thank you for verifying that. i have a file that matches "android-studio-ide-183.5692245-linux.tar.gz" in bytes yet the checksum is different. i just downloaded the older version whose hash checked out, installed and upgraded. Thank you.